# split at "|" and read filename and path to copy JAVA

Tags: java, file, split

I have a text file that looks like this `fileName | path`.
I read the text file and split it at the `|`. 
Now I want to use the filename and the path to copy files from one directory to another.

Here is what I have so far, the result I get is as follows:

```
file to be copied: test.jar to path: c:/test
c:\InstallFiles\test.jar
c:\test
c:\test
```

here is my code:

```
    String record = "";
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    String curDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    File file = new File(curDir + "/InstallFiles.txt");
    File installFiles = new File("c:/InstallFiles");
    File[] files = installFiles.listFiles();
    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        while ((record = myInput.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] recordColumns = record.split("\\|");

            String fileName = recordColumns[0].toString().trim();
            String path = recordColumns[1].toString().trim();

            System.out.println("file to be copied: " + fileName + " to path: " + path);
            Path source = Paths.get(installFiles +"/"+ fileName);
            System.out.println(source);
            Path target = Paths.get(path);
            System.out.println(target);
            Files.copy(source, target);
            System.out.println("Copied file: " + fileName + " to " + path);
        }
        myInput.close();
        fileReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Also, why are you calling `toString()` on a `String`?

Comment: What is the problem you have with this?

Comment: it does not copy the files from the InstallFiles folder to the test folder

Comment: String fileName = recordColumns[0].toString().trim(); If i dont do the toString it only return value of the column e.g 1 or 2 or 3

Comment: @user1794974: `recordColumns` is a `String[]`, so `recordColumns[0].toString().trim();` will always be the same as `recordColumns[0].trim();`

Comment: thanks i replaced it, still doesnt copy the files

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, some form of `IOException` is thrown. I cannot tell why from the information you are giving.

I would suggest that you change the code within the `catch` block to:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will probably yield better information about why the error occured.

---

**EDIT:**

One possible guess as to why the problem might occur is that the destination file (`c:\test`) already exists. According to [this javadoc documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29), that would cause you to get a `FileAlreadyExistsException` unless you specify a `REPLACE_EXISTING` option, which you have not done.